# selenium UI automation through Teamcity build agent

Tags: firefox, selenium, teamcity

We are running selenium UI automation through Teamcity build Agent but it couldnt launch firefox and the error is below:
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host localhost.localdomain on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
 Error: cannot open display: :0.0
 Error: cannot open display: :0.0

Before trying with Teamcity build agent , we have executed the selenium cases manually (by running the ant script) in the build agent VM and it could launch firefox and executed the cases successfully.

so, we don't see any problem of compatibilty between firefox and selenium jar version.

Comment: Are you suing remote webdriver?

Comment: No. we are not using remote webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your configuration misses a virtual display. 
You need a virtual display if you want to run selenium with a browser such as Firefox, IE, ..., without any display. You could use Xvfb for that, or headless browser such as phantomJS. 
There are a lot of articles about that, like [this one](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/38-headless)

Or you could export your display to a monitoring environment, if you want selenium tests to be displayed while they run.

Comment: Thanks for the information. The link that you have provided is having Ruby example. The selenium test that I am using is implemented with Java.  I would give a try to update the Java code accordingly as mentioned. Thanks again